# Why does `clEnqueueReadBuffer` break while debugging openCL host code?

Tags: opencl, amd-processor

```
__kernel void kmeans_kernel(__global float* data, int points, 
                            __global float* centroids, int clusters, 
                             int dimensions)
{           

    //extern __shared__ float storage_space[];
     __local float storage_space[];

    __local int iterations;
    __local float *means; 
    __local float *index; 
    __local float *mindist;
    __local float *s_data;


    iterations = points / ( get_global_size(0)) + 1;    


    if( get_local_id(0) == 0 ){
        s_data[get_local_id(0)] = data[get_local_id(0)];
        means=&storage_space[0];
        index=&storage_space[get_local_size(0)];
        mindist=&storage_space[2*get_local_size(0)];
    }

    //data = &data[blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x];
    data = &data[get_global_id(0)];         

    while( iterations )
    {
        mindist[get_local_id(0)] = 3.402823466e+38F;                
        index[get_local_id(0)] = 0;             

        for( short j = 0; j < clusters; j++ )
        {                       
            if( get_local_id(0) <= dimensions )
                //means[get_local_id(0)] = centroids[get_local_id(0)+j*c_pitch];
                means[get_local_id(0)] = centroids[get_local_id(0)+j];
            //__syncthreads();      
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE | CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

            if( !(data[get_local_id(0)] - s_data[get_local_id(0)] > points - 1) )
            {
                float dist = distance_gpu_transpose( means, data, dimensions);
                if( dist < mindist[get_local_id(0)] )
                {
                    mindist[get_local_id(0)] = dist;
                    index[get_local_id(0)] = j;
                }                   
            }           
            //__syncthreads();          
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE | CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }

        if( !(data[get_local_id(0)] - s_data[get_local_id(0)] > points - 1) )                               
                data[0] = index[get_local_id(0)];

        data += (get_global_size(0));               
        if( get_local_id(0) == 0 )
            --iterations;
        //__syncthreads();
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE | CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
}
```

I am using AMD processor with ATI 3200 graphics card, it does not support openCL but the rest of the code is running fine on CPU itself.

The problem with my code is quite complicated for me this time. After the kernel got executed, I am unable to read the device memory variable using `clEnqueueReadBuffer`. while dubugging it's breaking at this point and says,

```
Unhandled exception at 0x10001098 in CL_kmeans.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction.
```

When i press break here, it gives

```
No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed.
```

What might be the problem here? please suggest me some solution.
my kernel code is as given above and the statement i use to read data is,

```
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, gpu_data, CL_TRUE, 0,sizeof( float ) * instances->cols* 1 , instances->data, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

How can I check the possible errors here?

Comment: Can you say more about what OpenCL implementation you are using?  Is it AMD's implementation?  Are you using the CPU device?

Comment: Yes boiler96.. its AMD's implementation but the ATI card I am having is 3xxx series which doesnt support openCL..so its running on cpu..

Comment: My guess here is that the clEnqueueReadBuffer is the first blocking call after the clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.  If that's true, then I think the exception is caused by the code generated for your kernel.  Are you on an AMD CPU?

Comment: Yes am calling clEnqueueReadBuffer immediatly after clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.. how to know the exceptions generated from kernel bcz breakpoint wont work in kernel code..?? Yes I am using AMD CPU..

Comment: At this point, all I can guess is that you've found a bug in the AMD OpenCL SDK.  It appears to be generating instructions that aren't supported on your processor.